# Why do I get this error, "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."?

Tags: .net, .net-core, mvp, .net-standard

I'm trying a MVP implementation with my View being Windows Forms development (project set to .NET v4.6.2) and my model and presenter to be .NET Standard 1.5

I get a error passing the Forms view to the View interface to the Presenter, the error:

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I guess the issue is once the execution is handed to the Standard library the .NET System.Runtime library is not referenced in the .NET standard execution context? if so what do I need in the project.json to include this?

Here is my Project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
    "System.Net.Requests": "4.0.10.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {},
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are still using RC2. Please first upgrade to RTM by reading http://dot.net

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the same problem that ASP Core Projects have:
[Could not find System.Runtime 4.1.0.0 when running ASP.NET web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310518/could-not-find-system-runtime-4-1-0-0-when-running-asp-net-web-application/41414568#41414568)

Manually copying the right System.Runtime from the nuget cache into the bin will solve it until the bug is addressed...

**UPDATE:** If you use the latest .Net Core release (1.1) and binaries this is fixed. The tool preview is still on 1.0.1 so you have to make sure you install the binaries for 1.1.