# Can I write PowerShell binary cmdlet with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to create a basic PowerShell Module with a binary Cmdlet internals, cause writing things in PowerShell only doesn't look as convenient as in C#.

Following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878342(v=vs.85).aspx) guide, it looks like I have to:

- add [Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK](https://powershell.myget.org/feed/powershell-core/package/nuget/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK) to my `project.json`
- mark my cmdlet class with required attributes
- write manifest file, with `RootModule`, targeting my `.dll`
- put that `.dll` nearby manifest
- put both under `PSModulePath`

but, when I'm trying to `Import-Module`, PowerShell core complains on missing runtime:

```
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system
cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
```

Am I doing something wrong, or such tricky things are not supported yet as well?

Comment: Can you share your project.json?

Comment: See if this helps! http://stackoverflow.com/q/38310518/5212566 http://stackoverflow.com/a/37639003/5212566

Comment: Sorry, it's not actual for now

Answer (score 14):

This gets a lot easier with `.NET Core 2.0 SDK` and `Visual Studio 2017 Update 15.3` (or higher).  If you don't have VS, you can do this from the command line with the .NET Core 2.0 SDK.

The important bit is to add the `PowerShellStandard.Library 3.0.0-preview-01` (or higher) NuGet package to your project file (.csproj).

Here is a simple command line example:

```
cd $home
dotnet new classlib --name psmodule
cd .\psmodule
dotnet add package PowerShellStandard.Library --version 3.0.0-preview-01
Remove-Item .\Class1.cs
@'
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace PSCmdletExample
{
    [Cmdlet("Get", "Foo")]
    public class GetFooCommand : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        protected override void EndProcessing()
        {
            this.WriteObject("Foo is " + this.Name);
            base.EndProcessing();
        }
    }
}
'@ | Out-File GetFooCommand.cs -Encoding UTF8

dotnet build
cd .\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\
ipmo .\psmodule.dll
get-foo
```

To get this same command to run in Windows PowerShell 5.1 requires a bit more work.  You have to execute the following before the command will work:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\netstandard.dll"
```

Comment: Add-Type part helped me loading .NET Standard lib into PowerShell, thanks a lot!

Comment: No longer have to specify the version of `PowerShellStandard.Library` now. Default version just works. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

For netcore, there is a new template for powershell that you can install and use then you can modify the c# code.

- Installing the PowerShell Standard Module Template

```
$ dotnet new -i Microsoft.PowerShell.Standard.Module.Template
```

- Creating a New Module Project in a new folder

```
$ dotnet new psmodule
```

- Building the Module

```
dotnet build
```

For more details read [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/writing-portable-modules?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `PowerShell Core` to write a PowerShell CmdLet in .NET Core.

There is a guide here, including corrections to your `project.json`:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/master/docs/cmdlet-example

To summarize you need the following in your `project.json`

```
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies": "1.0.0-*"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.3": {
            "imports": [ "net40" ],
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.NETCore": "5.0.1-*",
                "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1-*"
            }
        }
    }
```