# Can I refer to a ".net core" project from a custom project (project template)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I have a custom project and I want to create a reference from this project to .net core (and .net 5) projects, I got the following error:

> '..\Core2\Core2.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp3.1'. It cannot be
> referenced by a project that targets
> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
> line 1662

1. Can the custom project be a ".net core"? it is .netframework (I think it is a default, it is not written in vstemplate/props/targets files.
2. Can a custom project refer to a .net core project?

Comment: The shared project between them all must be a .NET shared library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference a .NET Core Library in a .NET 4.6 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810504/reference-a-net-core-library-in-a-net-4-6-project)

Comment: Fixed by adding non empty environment variable "TargetRuntime"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding non empty environment variable "TargetRuntime"